# How do I improve photograph quality on my HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, photos

I think that I have my HTC Desire on the highest quality settings for taking pictures, but the quality of the photographs is awful. Is that a weakness of the Desire, or is there something that I can do to improve things?

In response to @George_Gaal's comment below I have uploaded two pictures. The top one was taken quite a long time ago and the quality is fine.

[image: A good, older one]

This one was taken last week and is completely out of focus. I wonder if I haven't inadvertently changed some settings? My phone did have to get a new board after it overheated. Could it be something to do with that?

[image: a bad, newer one]

Comment: Could you give us examples of this "awful photos"? Also, generally, more light sources give better photos.

Comment: Is it just my failing eyesight, or do corners of the "bad" photo look fine?  Not to sound condescending, but have you tried the obvious things like cleaning the optics and the transparent plastic covering it?  In addition to distorting the photos, smudges on the optics could cause the camera to not focus properly.  A microfiber cloth that everyone recommends for phone's screen also does wonders for the camera.

Comment: one thing I would check is that the camera lens is clean of smudges/scratches.

Comment: Ryan and Chahk, you should make your comments answers. I can't vote your comments up or thank you properly.

Comment: I've given everything a very good clean and still have the same problem. I suspect that the damage was done when the board was swapped out.

Answer (score 2):

have you seen this post http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=990596
Battery cover couses focus loss there is a youtube video on the post which makes a comparison, also sample pictures. hope this helps ;)

Comment: I love this answer, but in my specific case I don't think it s the solution tom my problem. I tried what the video suggested and it made no difference. I suspect my lens was actually moved in the repair process.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, if you see no change when the battery cover is removed, then, as you suggested, you may have issues with the lens. I still use my desire, but thinking about a change. HTC has stopped supporting this phone long ago.